# When entering taxonomy terms are new ones added with different pk even if term is already in the dictionary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I was expecting taxonomy terms to only be added if they weren't already in the dictionary. However, it seems that I have multiple terms added with different tid's or pk which I wasn't expecting. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal allows you to enter multiple terms with the same name. If you want to have unique term names, use the [Taxonomy dupecheck](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_dupecheck) module.

> Taxonomy dupecheck module prevents Drupal administrators from adding
>   duplicate taxonomy vocabularies and/or terms.